# How to remove metadata from adam file in 2sxc application

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

When using 2sxc app in dotnetnuke is easy to add and edit metadata for adam files,
but how to remove/delete metadata? Not only empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no quick solution, but you can always do it in the entity-management (app-admin > data)